# somar valores com atributos iguais numa lista python

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```python
list = [Despesa(10, 'Mercado'), Despesa(20, 'Mercado'), Despesa(10, 'Farmácia')]
```

o objeto Despesa recebe um valor=int e um nome=str.

Preciso de uma função que identifique as ocorrências de objetos com o nome, Mercado, por exemplo, e some os valores desse objeto, exemplo:

na list eu tenho dois objetos com o atributo 'Mercado', então eu deveria somar os valores destes dois objetos, a saída seria 30, nesse caso.

Comment: Percorra a lista, para cada item, compare se o nome é o desejado e, se sim, some o valor ao total. Quer tentar?

Comment: Tentei e funcionou, porém, isso funciona quando eu sei qual é o nome que eu quero, por exemplo, se o nome for 'Mercado' eu somo. Mas, se a lista possuir vários objetos Despesa consequentemente com vários nomes, como eu faria? Tipo, para todos os objetos Despesa que possuem um nome repetido eu somo os valores destes.

Comment: Faz essa soma em um dicionário onde o nome é a chave do dicionário.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore o código da outra resposta, *faz uso desnecessário, equivocado exagerado de orientação a objetos*, e faça conforme foi dito nos comentários mantenha um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) para guardar os resultados e percorra a lista de despesas elemento por elemento, e caso:

- o nome da despesa não seja chave no dicionário de resultados, crie uma nova chave no no dicionário de resultados com o nome da despesa e faça o valor da despesa ser o valor dessa chave.
- já exista uma chave no dicionário de resultados com o nome da despesa, some o valor dessa chave com o valor da despesa.

Lembrando que em Python as chaves de um dicionário são únicas e [hasheáveis](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) e que a função `dict.get(key, default)` retorna o valor da chave `dict[key]` e caso `dict[key]` não exista retorna `default`.

```python
from collections import namedtuple

#Declaração da classe Despesa como uma namedtuple.
Despesa = namedtuple('Despesa', ['valor', 'nome'])

lista = [Despesa(10, 'Mercado'), Despesa(20, 'Mercado'), Despesa(10, 'Farmácia')]

resultado = {}

#Para cada despesa d em lista...
for d in lista:
  resultado[d.nome] = resultado.get(d.nome, 0) + d.valor  #Na chave d.nome caso já existir obtém o seu valor e soma com d.valor. 
                                                          #Caso a chave d.nome não exista cria uma nova chave d.nome com o valor d.valor,

print(resultado)
#{'Mercado': 30, 'Farmácia': 10}
```

Referências:

- [collections.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
- [Tipo mapeamento — dict](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)
- [dict.get(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: Só respondi porque a outra resposta está muito mal escrita e ensina errado.

Comment: Tinha feito de uma forma parecida com a sua, porém um pouco mais complicada...

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @macacoprego: não agradeça, veja [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)